# How to check recent vscode's nodejs versions for develop vscode extension?

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I want to use nodejs new worker thread api(currently be stable in nodejs version 12) in vscode extension, just for better performance, but i couldn't find the check list mentions its electron version and nodejs version for each vscode version.

Could I find its nodejs version check list for developing vscode extension?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Help -> About` will tell you the version of pretty much everything involved (Electron, Chrome, Node.js, V8...):

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot Gama, that answer helps me to check current vscode version info on my computer .

I 've also found that versions info was  mentions on vscode office website's vscode update info page:
https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_40

.Those info help me remind user to know which version vscode won't support some of feature of the extension.